# Javascript. Run a AJAX flow after current AJAX stops

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So I have a simple javascript that loads more comments from a database when the user clicks More.
Now I would like to extend this script so that it first populates the SQL database before it starts letting users view the comments. And I feel that I'm on the right track but I can't get it to work.

First the code that does WORK.

```
$(function() {

$('.load_more').live("click",function() {


    var photoid = document.getElementById('photoid').value;
    var lastid = document.getElementById('lastid').value;


    if(lastid!='end'){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/more_comments_ajax.php",
        data: {
            photoid : photoid,
            lastid : lastid
        },
        beforeSend:  function() {
            $('a.load_more').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request

        },
        success: function(html){//html = the server response html code
            $("#more").remove();//Remove the div with id=more 
            $("div#updates").append(html);//Append the html returned by the server .


        }
        });

    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Now I feel that this should be possible to expand like this.

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/populate_sql.php",

        beforeSend:  function() {
            $('a.load_more').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request
        },

    sucess: $('.load_more').live("click",function() {


    var photoid = document.getElementById('photoid').value;
    var lastid = document.getElementById('lastid').value;


    if(lastid!='end'){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/more_comments_ajax.php",
        data: {
            photoid : photoid,
            lastid : lastid
        },
        beforeSend:  function() {
            $('a.load_more').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request

        },
        success: function(html){//html = the server response html code
            $("#more").remove();//Remove the div with id=more 
            $("div#updates").append(html);//Append the html returned by the server .


        }
        });

    }
    return false;
});
});
});
```

Where am I loosing it?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, or just a typo but `sucess: $('.load_more').live("click",function() {` success is spelt wrong, and should be in an anonymous function (e.g. `success: function(){ /* code here */ }`)

Comment: You didn't say how it was specifically failing. Is nothing happening? Is the .live('click'...) not working? Is the success function not firing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function. I used it before and it works great. after first callback receives then it send second request.

```
(function($) 
    {
        var ajaxQueue = $({});
        $.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) 
        {
            var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;
            ajaxQueue.queue(function(next)
            {
                ajaxOpts.complete = function() 
                {
                    if (oldComplete) oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);
                    next();
                };
                $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

use it like the normal ajax. sample:

```
      $.ajaxQueue({ url: 'x.php', data:{x:x,y:y}, type: 'POST', 
        success: function(respond) 
        {
            .....
        }
        });
```

so you can check if there was a callback from first ajax then send second request.
hope it helps you.

Comment: and you can check this out: [Retrying AJAX Requests with jQuery ajaxPrefilter](http://www.moretechtips.net/2012/04/retrying-ajax-requests-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. It was not exactly what I needed but it gave me an idea and the solution that works for me was 2 javascripts working together. I'm leaving the code here if someone needs something similar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
var pid = '<?php echo $ids['0']; ?>';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/prepare_sql.php",
data: "pid="+ pid,
beforeSend:  function() {
        $('div#updates').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request

    },
    success: function(html) {
        $("div#updates").replaceWith(html);
    }
});
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.load_more').live("click",function() {


var photoid = document.getElementById('photoid').value;
var lastid = document.getElementById('lastid').value;


if(lastid!='end'){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/more_comments_ajax.php",
    data: {
        photoid : photoid,
        lastid : lastid
    },
    beforeSend:  function() {
        $('a.load_more').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request

    },
    success: function(html){//html = the server response html code
        $("#more").remove();//Remove the div with id=more 
        $("div#updates").append(html);//Append the html returned by the server .


    }
    });

}
return false;
});

</script>
```